# MQ Copybook libraries

Tags: ibm-mq, copybook

In which library can we find layout of IBM supplied Mq copybooks(like CMQV, CMQODV) in COBOL.

By compilation am able to see the expanded copybooks but would like to know the library.

Comment: Does this help: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/8.0?topic=mq-data-definition-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say which platform.

- Windows: %MQ_INSTALLATION_PATH%\Tools\cobol\copybook
- UNIX: $MQ_INSTALLATION_PATH/inc/
- z/OS: hlq.SCSQCOBC